# Gmail smtp not working in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, smtp, gmail

1

Hi I am using gmail smtp with port 587. that is working fine on local but not working on production. my website is hosted on AWS EC2.

[image]

I have added the port in security group as well.

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First check your code is working or not by selecting `All traffic` range option.
[image: aws]
If that works then remove above setting and add it for 587 with other necessary port like `https` requires `443 port` etc.

Also check Outbound port Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You have opened a Custom TCP port. SMTP traffic can be handled through TCP but only at port 25 which is dedicated to SMTP via TCP ([see more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18833814/9273701)). What you need here is to add an outbound traffic rule (if you are trying to send an email **from** your instance) of type SMTP at port 587 in you security group.